# Joomla 1.5 Strict Standards error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

So, I have been asked by a family friend to take a look at their site. It has just recently turned into a big garbled mess of errors such as;
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /home/sitename/public_html/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 29

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /home/sitename/public_html/libraries/loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/sitename/public_html/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 462

I have been looking elsewhere and I have seen mention of changing error_reporting in configuration.php, I have changed it from 
var $error_reporting = '-1'; 
to 
var $error_reporting = '6135';

This removed a lot of the errors that was appearing on the page but there is still plenty that exist. Can anyone help me with clearing up the last lot of errors?

From what I can gather, the site is Joomla 1.5 which I know needs to be updated but if I can just get the errors to 'disappear' whilst I can work on updating the site or getting a new one built that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: What is your php version? Do you have access to your php.ini file?

Comment: Hi,
PHP Version 5.5.37
I have searched but I cannot find a php.ini file anywhere!

Comment: Add a `info.php` file in your site's root & add this php code `<?php phpinf(); ?>`, Then browse to yourdomain.com/info.php; In that page you will see that `loaded configuration file` that is your php.ini location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add `$error_reporting = 22516` if you are using `PHP 5.4.x`
- Add `$error_reporting = 22519` if you are using `PHP 5.3.x`
- Add `$error_reporting = 6133` if you are using `PHP 5.2.x`

And if you have php.ini access, find `error_reporting` and assign `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED`

IF doesn't work

in your `index.php` after `define( '_JEXEC', 1 );` add `error_reporting(0);` if not work, replace with `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);` Also, after each change if not work, check the `error_reporting` value in info page.

OR if you don't want to see any error, contact your host to disable `display_errors` or if you have access to php.ini then do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am using PHP 5.5.x? and I have done as you mentioned earlier and created a php.info page,
It tells me that php.ini is, /usr/local/lib/php.ini but I have tried to navigate to this in CPanel and it cannot find anything. It looks like to get to php.ini I would have to contact the hosting company.
Thanks

Comment: @user3029356 My Pleasure. If my answer helped your question, don't forget to mark the answer.

Comment: I still have the problem unfortunately. 

I do not have php.ini access and changing the $error_reporting resolved some of the error messages but there are still some there. 

Can you help anymore? 

Thanks

Comment: @user3029356 : Try adding `$error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED` in Joomla configuration file. Also, at the info page, what is the master and local value of `error_reporting`?

Comment: adding $error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED actually created more errors showing up on the website. I have changed it back to $error_reporting = '6135'

The master and local value is showing as 24567.

Also, just to check, I am editing the configuration.php file, that is titled 

class JConfig

Comment: in your index.php after `define( '_JEXEC', 1 );` add `error_reporting(0);` if not work, replace with `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);` Also, after each change if not work, check the `error_reporting` value in info page.

Comment: Thank you arif, I added, error_reporting(0); into my index.php, that has resolved the problem.

Comment: @user3029356 Great ! Glad to hear about this :)